# Circular dependency was detected when I tried to implement state pattern

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dependencies, state-pattern, di-containers

I am having this issue:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A circular dependency was detected
> for the service of type 'LibraryExamples.Water.States.IGasState'.
> LibraryExamples.Water.IWater(LibraryExamples.Water.WaterMe) ->
> LibraryExamples.Water.IWaterStateFactory(LibraryExamples.Water.WaterStateFactory)
> -> LibraryExamples.Water.States.IGasState(LibraryExamples.Water.States.GasState)
> -> LibraryExamples.Water.States.ILiquidState(LibraryExamples.Water.States.LiquidState)
> -> LibraryExamples.Water.States.IGasState'

```cs
namespace LibraryExamples.Water.States
{
    public class GasState : IGasState
    {
        private readonly ILiquidState LiquidState;

        public GasState(ILiquidState nextState)
        {
            this.LiquidState = nextState;
        }

        public IWaterState Heat()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Already in a gaseous state. Heating has no effect.");

            return this;
        }

        public IWaterState Cool()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cooling gas (steam) turns it into liquid water.");

            return this.ToLiquidState();
        }

        public void Describe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current state: Gas");
        }

        public ILiquidState ToLiquidState()
        {
            return this.LiquidState;
        }
    }
}
namespace LibraryExamples.Water.States
{
    public interface IGasState : IWaterState
    {

        ILiquidState ToLiquidState();
    }
}
namespace LibraryExamples.Water.States
{
    public interface ILiquidState : IWaterState
    {
        IGasState ToGasState();
    }
}
namespace LibraryExamples.Water.States
{
    public interface ISolideState : IWaterState
    {
        ILiquidState ToLiquidState();
    }
}
namespace LibraryExamples.Water.States
{
    public class LiquidState : ILiquidState
    {
        private readonly IGasState GasState;

        private readonly ISolideState solideState;

        public LiquidState(IGasState GastState, ISolideState solideState)
        {
            this.GasState = GastState;
            this.solideState = solideState;
        }

        public IWaterState Cool()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cooling liquid water turns it into solid water.");

            return this.ToSolidState();
        }

        public IWaterState Heat()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Heating liquid water turns into gas water");

            return this.ToGasState();
        }

        public void Describe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current state: Solid");
        }

        public IGasState ToGasState()
        {
            return this.GasState;
        }

        public ISolideState ToSolidState()
        {
            return this.solideState;
        }
    }
}
namespace LibraryExamples.Water.States
{
    public class SolidState : ISolideState
    {
        private readonly ILiquidState LiquidState;

        public SolidState(ILiquidState liquidState)
        {
            this.LiquidState = liquidState;
        }

        public IWaterState Heat()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Heating solid water turns it into liquid water.");

            return this.ToLiquidState();
        }

        public IWaterState Cool()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Already solid. Cooling has no effect.");

            return this;
        }

        public void Describe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current state: Solid");
        }

        public ILiquidState ToLiquidState()
        {
            return this.LiquidState;
        }
    }
}
namespace LibraryExamples.Water
{
    public interface IWater
    {
        void Cool();
        void DescribeState();
        void Heat();
    }
}
namespace LibraryExamples.Water
{
    public interface IWaterState
    {
        IWaterState Heat();
        IWaterState Cool();
        void Describe();
    }
}
namespace LibraryExamples.Water
{
    public class Water : IWater
    {
        private IWaterState State;

        public Water(IWaterState initialState)
        {
            this.State = initialState;
        }

        public void Heat()
        {
            this.State.Heat();
        }

        public void Cool()
        {
            this.State.Cool();
        }

        public void DescribeState()
        {
            this.State.Describe();
        }
    }
}
```

I am having this issue:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A circular dependency was detected
> for the service of type 'LibraryExamples.Water.States.IGasState'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you are trying to do. As an example, a "gas state" doesn't need a "liquid state".

Comment: in the gas state we have liquid state it is process followws colling water gas => liquid

Comment: The way you have designed your interfaces and classes is weird. Water can have a state and the state can be changed via `Heat()` and `Cool()`. But your current implementation requires that a `GasState()` instance require a liquid state. The state transition should be somehow managed in the water class, not in the three state classes. A "state" usually can't do anything itself, it just "is".

Comment: Matter can exist is one of four states, solid, liquid, gas, or plasma.  Or as perhaps something in between.  So it makes no sense for a "liquid" to inherit nor implement a "gas" state.  So think about what you actually need from a business perspective.  What are states, properties, actions etc.  Once you think this through, then you should be able to design your classes and interfaces in the right manner (of course you only need to implement what you project required, not everything).

Comment: the liquid does not inherit or implement, it uses IGasState to give it back to the water class, the idea here is to design a state pattern using interfaces and DI, IoC

Comment: Still GasState and SolidState need each other. In a DI framework the things injected via constructors aren't optional. If you would create the classes by hand you would stumble over the same thing what to create first? You couldn't and would inject null and then try to fix that by other means later(a property for example). There are a gazillions of typical pattern that make logically sense and work technically here. They end up having the logic in something third that can be injected.

Comment: So let the State classes just be that states and do the state change in a third class. Maybe call that Statemachine and do the actual statechange in that class.

Comment: @Ralf, services classes must not be created by hand data object are, yeah by using a satate factory I can get the next state instance but I am thinking keep it way from factory just state

Comment: @S.LaBani Your `IGasState` like interfaces aren't really "service classes" to begin with. A state machine might make more sense for what you are trying to do. The interface `IWaterState` (and therefore all its sub interfaces) shouldn't have the methods `Heat()` and `Cool()` methods. You can heat/cool water, not states.

Comment: @Progman , I said state pattern is statemchine

Answer (score 0):

To be able to work with DI, we must use a lazy creation of the aggregate states to avoid circular references. I will be using a `Lazy<IAggregateState>` for this. Note that we cannot completely avoid factories, as `Lazy<T>` requires a factory delegate.

We declare only one interface for the different states to be able to access and work with them in the same way and will be using keyed services introduced in .NET 8.0 to differentiate the different states.

```cs
public interface IAggregateState
{
    IAggregateState? CoolerState { get; }
    IAggregateState? HotterState { get; }

    string Description { get; }
}
```

The aggregate states have references to the cooler and hotter states, so that we can link them together in a logical way. Note that the states are nullable, as the coolest state has no predecessor and the hottest state has no successor.

Except for the description, all the states have the same implementation. Therefore, we implement a base state as an abstract class.

```cs
public abstract class AggregateState(Lazy<IAggregateState>? cooler,
    Lazy<IAggregateState>? hotter) : IAggregateState
{
    public abstract string Description { get; }

    public IAggregateState? CoolerState => cooler?.Value;

    public IAggregateState? HotterState => hotter?.Value;
}
```

We can no derive the different states. Note that we specify a service key for the aggregate states through the `FromKeyedServicesAttribute`:

```cs
public class Solid([FromKeyedServices("liquid")]Lazy<IAggregateState> hotter) : 
    AggregateState(null, hotter)
{
    public override string Description => "Aggregate state: Solid";
}

public class Liquid(
    [FromKeyedServices("solid")]Lazy<IAggregateState> cooler,
    [FromKeyedServices("gaseous")]Lazy<IAggregateState> hotter) :
    AggregateState(cooler, hotter)
{
    public override string Description => "Aggregate state: Liquid";
}

public class Gaseous([FromKeyedServices("liquid")]Lazy<IAggregateState> cooler) :
    AggregateState(cooler, null)
{
    public override string Description => "Aggregate state: Gaseous";
}
```

---

Not only water has aggregate states. Therefore, instead of having an interface `IWater`, I declare a more general interface:

```cs
public interface IMatter
{
    IAggregateState State { get; }
    void Heat();
    void Cool();
    string Name {  get; }
    string Description { get; }
}
```

Here, only the Name will be different for different kinds of matter and the description is supposed to be constructed from the matter name and the current aggregate state. Therefore, we implement matter as an abstract class again:

```cs
public abstract class Matter(IAggregateState initialState) : IMatter
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public string Description => $"{Name}: {State.Description}";

    public IAggregateState State { get; private set; } = initialState;

    public void Cool()
    {
        State = State.CoolerState ?? State;
    }

    public void Heat()
    {
        State = State.HotterState ?? State;
    }
}
```

If the cooler or hotter sates are `null`, we just keep the same state by using the null-coalesce operator.

```cs
public class Water([FromKeyedServices("liquid")] IAggregateState initialState) : Matter(initialState)
{
    public override string Name => "Water";
}
```

---

Now, we can set up DI. I am adding the states as transients and the `Lazy<T>` as singletons. `Lazy<T>` inherently returns a singleton.

```cs
IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddKeyedTransient<IAggregateState, Solid>("solid");
        services.AddKeyedTransient<IAggregateState, Liquid>("liquid");
        services.AddKeyedTransient<IAggregateState, Gaseous>("gaseous");
        services.AddKeyedSingleton<Lazy<IAggregateState>>("solid",
            (sp, key) => new Lazy<IAggregateState>(() => sp.GetRequiredKeyedService<IAggregateState>(key)));
        services.AddKeyedSingleton<Lazy<IAggregateState>>("liquid",
            (sp, key) => new Lazy<IAggregateState>(() => sp.GetRequiredKeyedService<IAggregateState>(key)));
        services.AddKeyedSingleton<Lazy<IAggregateState>>("gaseous",
            (sp, key) => new Lazy<IAggregateState>(() => sp.GetRequiredKeyedService<IAggregateState>(key)));
        services.AddKeyedTransient<IMatter, Water>("water");
    });
IHost host = builder.Build();
IMatter matter = host.Services.GetKeyedService<IMatter>("water")!;

Console.WriteLine(matter.Description);
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    if (Random.Shared.NextDouble() < 0.5) {
        Console.WriteLine("> cooling...");
        matter.Cool();
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("> heating...");
        matter.Heat();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(matter.Description);
}
```

It will print something like this:

```
Water: Aggregate state: Liquid
> heating...
Water: Aggregate state: Gaseous
> cooling...
Water: Aggregate state: Liquid
> cooling...
Water: Aggregate state: Solid
> cooling...
Water: Aggregate state: Solid
> heating...
Water: Aggregate state: Liquid
> heating...
Water: Aggregate state: Gaseous
> heating...
Water: Aggregate state: Gaseous
> cooling...
Water: Aggregate state: Liquid
> cooling...
Water: Aggregate state: Solid
> cooling...
Water: Aggregate state: Solid
> heating...
Water: Aggregate state: Liquid
> heating...
Water: Aggregate state: Gaseous
```

Comment: where is the benfit of this, you missed the objectif where is the IoC and the use of the DI container, the class that will use the water will not setup the water nor any other class, a factory can help me get the state for hot and cool actions my question can be this implemented withut any factory

Comment: Because of the circular reference this would create, I don't think it is possible. We must create the states before we can link them, because they reference each other.

Comment: I agree with you, so the conclusion applying state design pattern to finite state machine with bidirectional transitions can be only achieved with help of the factory pattern.

Comment: Finally I found a way to do it with DI and rewrote my answer; however, setting up the services is quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I have already added an answer using keyed services and was wondering if a solution with specialized interfaces would work instead. But I ran into the problem that the class `Lazy<T>` is not covariant. Finally I could solve it by implementing a covariant lazy class. Only interfaces and delegates can be variant. Therefore, I declare:

```cs
public interface ILazy<out T> // the 'out' keyword makes it covariant.
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class CovariantLazy<T>(Func<T> valueFactory)
    : Lazy<T>(valueFactory), ILazy<T>
{
}
```

Note that I did implement only the members and constructors required for this solution. It is interesting to note that in C# a derived class can implement an interface solely by inheriting the required members from a base class.

---

We declare the aggregate state interfaces like this:

```cs
public interface IAggregateState
{
    IAggregateState? CoolerState { get; }
    IAggregateState? HotterState { get; }

    string Description { get; }
}
public interface ISolid : IAggregateState { }
public interface ILiquid : IAggregateState { }
public interface IGaseous : IAggregateState { }
```

The implementation now works against the `ILazy<T>` interface:

```cs
public abstract class AggregateState(
    ILazy<IAggregateState>? cooler, ILazy<IAggregateState>? hotter)
    : IAggregateState
{
    public abstract string Description { get; }

    public IAggregateState? CoolerState => cooler?.Value;

    public IAggregateState? HotterState => hotter?.Value;
}

public class Solid(ILazy<ILiquid> hotter)
    : AggregateState(null, hotter), ISolid
{
    public override string Description => "Aggregate state: Solid";
}

public class Liquid(ILazy<ISolid> cooler, ILazy<IGaseous> hotter)
    : AggregateState(cooler, hotter), ILiquid
{
    public override string Description => "Aggregate state: Liquid";
}

public class Gaseous(ILazy<ILiquid> cooler)
    : AggregateState(cooler, null), IGaseous
{
    public override string Description => "Aggregate state: Gaseous";
}
```

---

Similarly I declare and implement matter and water:

```cs
public interface IMatter
{
    IAggregateState State { get; }
    void Heat();
    void Cool();
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
}
public interface IWater : IMatter { }

public abstract class Matter(IAggregateState initialState) : IMatter
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public string Description => $"{Name}: {State.Description}";

    public IAggregateState State { get; private set; } = initialState;

    public void Cool()
    {
        State = State.CoolerState ?? State;
    }

    public void Heat()
    {
        State = State.HotterState ?? State;
    }
}

public class Water(ILiquid initialState) : Matter(initialState), IWater
{
    public override string Name => "Water";
}
```

---

We can now register the services like this:

```cs
IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddTransient<ISolid, Solid>();
        services.AddTransient<ILiquid, Liquid>();
        services.AddTransient<IGaseous, Gaseous>();
        services.AddSingleton<ILazy<ISolid>>(
            sp => new CovariantLazy<ISolid>(() => sp.GetService<ISolid>()!));
        services.AddSingleton<ILazy<ILiquid>>(
            sp => new CovariantLazy<ILiquid>(() => sp.GetService<ILiquid>()!));
        services.AddSingleton<ILazy<IGaseous>>(
            sp => new CovariantLazy<IGaseous>(() => sp.GetService<IGaseous>()!));
        services.AddTransient<IWater, Water>();
    });
IHost host = builder.Build();
```

I get the water for the console test like this:

```cs
IMatter matter = host.Services.GetService<IWater>()!;
```

The test itself remains the same as in the other answer.